# Ellipsis overflow in glance widget

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, glance

Is there any way how to make Glance `Text` overflow ellipsis? (Three dots, if text is too long).
In Jetpack compose, there is `overflow` parameter, but in Glance not...

Answer (score 1):

Just set `maxLines` attribute to the `Text` and the ellipsis will be applied automatically

```
Text(
    text = text,
    maxLines = 2,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `maxLines`.

```
Text(
    text = text,
    maxLines = 1,
)
```